# Excel SUMPRODUCT to rank , duplicating same rank for the product

Tags: excel-formula, sumproduct

I have a list of products that are sold in different regions. To find top opportunity though, I need to look at the National level. I am trying to rank product using sumproduct with countif but not getting desired result.

[image]

I have used following formula

```
ROUND(SUMPRODUCT((E3<$E$3:$E$11)/COUNTIF($B$3:$B$11,B3))+1,0)
```

Please help how can I achieve the required result

Comment: Why would E be ranked 5 while A is ranked 4?

Comment: As these are 2 diff products and would like to give diff rank

Comment: So is the tie resolved randomly or by sort order or alphabetically...?  And this raises another question, why does C get ranked as both 2 and 3?

Comment: You have same rank for different products for rank 3, so that contradicts. Wouldn't you rather rank either per region or per product?